# How to add a new item to strong parameters with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, parameter-passing, url-parameters, strong-parameters

Rails version: 5

I want to post a new item named `urls` to rails from frontend.

```
export function printPosts(params) {
  const endpoint = `v1/posts/print`
  return http.post(endpoint, params).then(({ data }) => data)
}
```

But in the `post` object, there isn't an item naming `urls`.
Something like `id`, `title`, `body`, `url` in it.

When I post to this endpoint, the logs showed

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"urls"=>"https://www.example.com/post/url/1\nhttps://www.example.com/post/url/2", "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"v1/posts", "action"=>"print", "post"=>{}} permitted: false>
undefined method `strip' for 1:Integer
```

`permitted: false` maybe means the `urls` doesn't allowed to be sent.

I added it to rails' `app/controllers/v1/posts_controller.rb` controller

```
private

def post_params
  params.permit(
    :urls
  )
end
```

Then print its value:

```
def print
  p post_params.to_h.symbolize_keys
end
```

Shown

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"urls"=>"https://www.example.com/post/url/1\nhttps://www.example.com/post/url/2", "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"v1/posts", "action"=>"print", "post"=>{}} permitted: false>
Unpermitted parameters: :format, :post
{:urls=>"https://www.example.com/post/url/1\nhttps://www.example.com/post/url/2"}
undefined method `strip' for 1:Integer
```

Comment: Where is `undefined method strip` coming from in your code?

Comment: I would really split this string into an array on the client side and send an array to your API. Your API should not have to clean up the problems of your front-end